# What do "случайно" and "не случайно" mean?

Tags: выбор-слова

Somebody sent me a letter that included this sentence

> Извини, это я сделала не случайно.

I looked up *случайно* and it had the definition

> accidentally, by accident, casually, by chance

So I assumed ***не*** случайно meant *not accidentally*, i.e. *on purpose*. But the person who wrote me said *не случайно* means *on accident*.

Does the negation of the word really mean the same thing, or am I missing something?

Comment: "Does the negation of the word really mean the same thing" no

Comment: Gramatically, this means: "Sorry, I did it intentionally". It's impossible to tell whether your correspondent meant it or not without additional context.

Comment: @Quassnoi I think I figured it out. I think there was a confusion betweeon "нечаянно" and "случайно".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. It's probably just a typo. Your assumptions about the meaning of ***не*** *случайно* are correct.

Comment: I agree. I can only add that the person who wrote the letter probably wanted to write "не нарочно", which means "not on purpose", but then corrected it for "случайно" and forgot to delete the negation.